# Vehicle Alternator/Inverter system

Tags: batteries, inverter, alternator

I have a food van with a stock alternator on the engine, and a 3000w inverter setup. The inverter setup uses 2 Trojan leisure batteries. Somehow the inverter setup is also linked to the alternator (I’m sure of this). I have only ever used this for small items like a travel kettle or phone charging. Today I purchased a Slush machine which is rated at 920w. I tried it on the inverter and it ran for a few mins, however as soon as the compressor kicked in the inverter switched off.

The inverter is rated at 3100w continuous power, and 6200w peak power for 1 second.

When the compressor kicks in and inverter switches off, the watt meter on the inverter displays 1920watts.

Now obviously it’s clear that the inverter cannot run the slush machine, so I was wondering what possible solution there are out there.

I should also add that the inverter and batteries were not used for around 18 month prior to fitting the slush machine. What would be the best way to test their batteries? Voltmeter?

I was thinking of adding a second alternator in the engine, would this work to provide enough power to the inverter and it’s batteries to power the slush machine.

Comment: Realistically you should seek practical advice from experienced people in your industry.  For better or more worse most food trucks I've seen run a generator independent of the vehicle engine.

Comment: Hi everyone in my area has static pitches so use a generator, I am the only mobile person, hence would prefer and inverter system.

Comment: What wiring are you using between the battery and the inverter? 3000W @12V is close to 300A. If the wiring is not heavy enough the voltage will drop to the point that the inverter will trip.

Comment: Use a "peak hold" meter to capture the minimum battery voltage, at the inverter, when the compressor starts. It's likely the batteries are tired and their voltage drops when heavily loaded, which leads the inverter to shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Can you borrow a current meter and see what the slushy machine is drawing when the compressor kicks in? Then try the same test, using the inverter to see what's tripping it up. Maybe your specific inverter isn't up to the task, but another one might be. Or there may be an issue with the wiring to the inverter (too much IR drop maybe?)

To your thought, they do make 110V alternators for underhood. Example here: https://www.fabcopower.com/generat/bgen.htm  Major drawback of this approach: you have to run the engine at a specific RPM to get the correct 60Hz, so that means something to set the throttle, too. Your customers won't like breathing the engine fumes or hearing the noise.

A sure-fire solution (and possibly cheaper, considering installation) would be a small gennie to run the machine.

EDIT: check the battery condition. If they’ve been sitting unused they may have sulfated and thus will not be putting out enough peak current for the compressor start-up.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses, the a generator would not work as there is not space in the van, and it is a mobile food van so goes from street to street. Hence the reason the engine will be always switched on anyway. The inverter has a watt meter ?? ( I think it’s called that) on it and the inverter switches of at around 1920w.

Comment: When I tried the machine at home ok mains, it worked perfectly and the compressor was on, is there anyway I can switch form mains at home to the inverter, whilst keeping the compressor (on the slush machine) switched on.

Comment: On the slush machine it says it draws 5.4A at 240v

Comment: Your question says 920W for the machine, but 5.4A at 240V is 1300W. But your wattmeter is saying the inverter conks out at 1920... can you measure the draw when connected to mains? Also, make sure the 12V wire to the inverter is big enough to carry the current.

Comment: However star he it may seem, your right. The machine says 920w and 5.4A @ 230-240v. The wattmeter says 1920w.  The inverter/batteries has previously been used with a slush machine (then unused for around 18 months) and now used again with a new machine, so I think the battery cables are okay. Could it be possible that the batteries are low on power?

Comment: If one or more of the batteries has sulfated it won’t be putting out enough ‘cranking’ current (this will likely be the case if they haven’t been on trickle charge.) Get a voltmeter and watch the +12V at the inverter input. It’s probably dipping when the compressor kicks in.

Comment: Hi I have checked this and the inverter voltmeter shows 9.9v and the inverts has a built in 10v cut off? Does this mean the batteries are knackered?

Comment: Most likely, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I would test the Slush machine on a known stable supply - you need to establish the starting characteristics of the compressor.

Some recommend that the inverter capacity has to be 5 times the rated load... 5 * 920 = 4600W, so you will probably need a different inverter or consider the other solutions from hacktastical.

Comment: My inverter is rated at 3100w continuous proper, surely it would have at least 6200w to start the compressor.

Comment: @Abcd123 did you evaluate the compressor starting load? Without that knowledge... why do you say your 3000W has a 6200W capacity? Source for that or just a guess...

Comment: Hi the source is from specs listed online at

Comment: http://www.autosessive.com/products/61514/ring-powersourcepro-3100-msw-12v-inverter-3100w

Comment: @Abcd123 add this info to your question properly, not everyone trawls through comments to piece together questions.

Comment: @Abcd123 And you **still** have not given any info about the compressor starting characteristics... Until you find out what is happening...

Comment: Thanks, original question updated. Also how can I measure the compressor starting characteristics, what I do know is that when the compressor kicks in and inverter switches off, the watt meter on the inverter is at 1920watts.